# TFTP Server in Altium nanoboard using TSK3000A

Tags: fpga, tftp

Is there any TFTP Server for Altium Nanoboard NB3000 using the processor TSK3000A.
The example from the Altium gives a webserver and it doesnt use any file system.

I need to transfer a file from PC to Altium board using Ethernet. Also let me if there is any other way of doing this. I Had used TFTP earlier, so i prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a processor which can run one of popular embedded OS's, e.g. Nios II, LM32, OpenRISC or another and run Linux, FreeRTOS, RTEMS or may be ECos on that processor.
This way you can implement TFTP or FTP or even NFS.

I am not too sure what OS can TSK3000A run. If you are planning to use this processor, perhaps best point of contact is either Altium technical support or community forum.